# Is it possible to deploy Spinnaker to an instance smaller than m4.xlarge on AWS?

Tags: spinnaker

We are currently following the default deployment instructions for Spinnaker which states using **m4.xlarge** as the instance type.
http://www.spinnaker.io/v1.0/docs/creating-a-spinnaker-instance#section-amazon-web-services

We did make an unsuccessful attempt to deploy it to m4.large but the services didnt start.

Has anyone tried the something similar and succeeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the size of your cloud.

There are 4 core services that you need - gate/deck/orca/clouddriver. You can shut the other ones off if say, you don't care about automated triggers, baking or jenkins integration.

I'm able to run this locally with the docker images with about 8 gigs of ram and it works. Using s3 instead of cassandra also helps here.

You can play around with the settings in the baked image of spinnaker, but for internal demos and what not, I've been able to just spin up a VM, install docker and run the docker compose config correctly on m4.large.

Comment: Tried to deploy to a smaller instance again (t2.large) and it worked. Also stopped some of the services we were not using.